# Put empty in query cause error with ojdbc8

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, junit

I've a maven project with Spring (5.2.11.RELEASE), Hibernate (5.4.25.Final) connected to an Oracle database (19c). I use ojdbc8 (19.6.0.0)

I have severals Junit (4.12) test which use query (native or HQL) with empty parameter.
It causes error like this :

```
java.lang.AssertionError:  valOffset: -1 this.length: 2 valLen: 0
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DynamicByteArray.updateDigest(DynamicByteArray.java:563)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.getRuntimeKey(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1311)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ResultSetCache.getResultSetCacheEntry(ResultSetCache.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.getCachedQueryResult(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3628)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.cacheQueryResultIfAppropriate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3616)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1173)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2304)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2057)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2019)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641)
at fr.cnrs.dsi.silab.commun.dao.flux.tutelle.CommunFluxMessageCustomDAOImpl.testQueryNativeEmpty(CommunFluxMessageCustomDAOImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:658)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:622)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.testQueryNativeEmpty(Unknown Source)
at fr.cnrs.dsi.silab.jms.dao.referentiel.TutelleNetaDaoTest.testFindPtf(TutelleNetaDaoTest.java:90)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

But before I used ojdbc6 and it worked well without error.
I noticed that this error is just into Junit test but not when the application run.

Exemple of query which causes error (One with native query, one other with HSL) :

```
// Native Query
@Override
public BigDecimal testQueryNativeEmpty(String empty) {
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("SELECT count(1) from silab.system_param sp ");
    queryString.append("where sp.spm_code = :empty ");

    Query query = entitymanager.createNativeQuery(queryString.toString());
    query.setParameter("empty", empty);

    return (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();
}

// HQL Query
@Query("select count(sp) from CommunSystemParam sp where sp.id = :empty")
BigDecimal testQueryHQLEmpty(String empty);


// Test with native query
BigDecimal count1 = fluxMessageDAO.testQueryNativeEmpty("CONST_ANNEE_EXE");
BigDecimal count2 = fluxMessageDAO.testQueryNativeEmpty("");
// Test with HQL Query
BigDecimal count3 = fluxMessageDAO.testQueryHQLEmpty("CONST_ANNEE_EXE");
BigDecimal count4 = fluxMessageDAO.testQueryHQLEmpty("");
```

It broke after execution of the line 2 (count2 or count4), the first goes well

Note that it's same result (error) If I put null instead of ""
(The type of spm_code is VARCHAR2(50))

I search everywhere but I can't find anything that can explain that in ojdbc8 it's different than ojdbc6. (I tested ojdbc10 and same result as ojdbc8)

I have the impression that I'm the only one to get that error.

Can you help me to fix it ?

Comment: Please edit the question and show a [mcve] of the java code.  thanks

Comment: Done. I put the version of my component. tell me if you need other information

Comment: what's the type of spm_code ?

Comment: Can you pls share longer stack trace? Also I'm not sure about this `sp.spm_code = :empty` it is Oracle compliant SQL, but does JDBC support named bind variables? AFAIK Oracle's JDBC parses provided SQL and replaces question marks which cooked binds on background.  But I never saw this mechanism failing.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The type is VARCHAR2(50)

Comment: @ibre5041 I put the full stacktrace. I added the method with HQL bug same error here.